# C# writing object to binary file

Tags: c#, .net

I have to write an object in to binary file.My struct looks like this.

```
   Struct Company
    {
       int numberofemployees
       list of Struct Employee.
    }

    Struct Employee
    {
       string EmployeeName;
       string Designation;
    }
```

What is the best way to do the above operation? 
Regards
Raju

Comment: Why is this a struct? Those don't look like good uses for `struct`, and I expect this is going to bite you in interesting ways. I would use a `class` here...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What exactly do you want the output to look like? You can write it manually (see Lirik's answer), or if you want runtime support, perhaps something like protobuf-net.

This would be trivial to do if you were using classes (which I expect you actually should be), but additionally protobuf-net v2 (only available as source at the moment) should work with that "as is".

For info, here is how I would do it as classes:

```
    public class Company
    {
        private readonly List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
        public List<Employee> Employees { get { return employees;}}
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public string EmployeeName {get;set;}
        public string Designation {get;set;}
    }
```

This could be decorated with serialization attributes, or (again, using protobuf-net v2) something like this test (which passes):

```
    [Test]
    public void CanSerializeCompany()
    {
        var model = TypeModel.Create();
        model.Add(typeof(Company), false).Add("Employees");
        model.Add(typeof(Employee), false).Add("EmployeeName", "Designation");
        model.CompileInPlace();

        Company comp = new Company {
            Employees = {
                new Employee { Designation = "Boss", EmployeeName = "Fred"},
                new Employee { Designation = "Grunt", EmployeeName = "Jo"},
                new Employee { Designation = "Scapegoat", EmployeeName = "Alex"}}
        }, clone;
        using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
            model.Serialize(ms, comp);
            ms.Position = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Bytes: " + ms.Length);
            clone = (Company) model.Deserialize(ms, null, typeof(Company));
        }
        Assert.AreEqual(3, clone.Employees.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("Boss", clone.Employees[0].Designation);
        Assert.AreEqual("Alex", clone.Employees[2].EmployeeName);
    }
```

(and writes 46 bytes)

It *should* work with private fields, structs, etc - I'd have to take a look...

If you are able to add attributes, then you don't need to set up the model manually (the first 4 lines). The rest of the code is just showing full round-trip usage.

Answer (score 10):

In my understanding, [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(VS.80).aspx) is the tool for this job.

**Edit:** As Marc explains in the comments, BinaryFormatter has certain disadvantages. He recommends [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) in his blog.

Comment: +1 Jens, that looks better than simply writing to file yourself.

Comment: I have tried using Binary Formatter. It is adding some header before writing first object in to the file. I don't want any header data.

Comment: Yes you do, it gives you a fighting chance to read the data back properly some day.

Comment: Honestly, `BinaryFormatter` is generally a **really** bad choice for persistence....

Comment: @Marc: Can you explain a little? I am using BinaryFormatter for something like that, and I'd be interested to know if (and why) I've made a bad choice. =)

Comment: It is hugely brittle; it is fine as long as you never change runtime, never change your assemblies, never obfuscate, and never change the code (for example auto-props). Additionally, it is *completely* .NET specific (non-portable). See http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/03/obfuscation-serialization-and.html

Comment: Oh, and it is unnecessarily verbose and CPU intensive. And consider that alternatives exist that are *not* brittle (they are contract-based rather than metadata-based), take fewer bytes, less CPU *and* are portable between different platforms...

Answer (score 7):

[Here is an example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/File-Stream/ReadandWriteaBinaryFile.htm) how you can read/write a binary file:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public class BinaryFileTest {

    private static void Main() {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("test.dat", FileMode.Create);
        BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(fs);

        w.Write(1.2M);
        w.Write("string");
        w.Write("string 2");
        w.Write('!');
        w.Flush();
        w.Close();
        fs.Close();

        fs = new FileStream("test.dat", FileMode.Open);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
        fs.Position = 0;
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        Console.WriteLine(br.ReadDecimal());
        Console.WriteLine(br.ReadString());
        Console.WriteLine(br.ReadString());
        Console.WriteLine(br.ReadChar());
        fs.Close();

    }
}
```