# Saving an Int16 List to a binary file

Tags: c#, serialization

I need to save data to a binary file.  It is of type `List<Int16>`.  How can I write this data to the file?

Comment: In what format do you want the result? Just saying "binary" is a bit vague. Can you post a specific example of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: remember to format the code: <> disappear otherwise

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# writing object to binary file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598929/c-writing-object-to-binary-file)

Answer (score 3):

```
    using(var file =  File.Create("out.bin"))
    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(file))
    {
        foreach (short value in list)
        {
            writer.Write(value);
        }
    }
```

note this assumes you want to use your CPUs endianness.

Comment: Probably a good idea to write an integer at the start to say how many items are in the list, although you could infer it by dividing the file size by 2.

Comment: @Jim true enough - it comes down to how you want it to look **exactly** ultimately. You can also just detect the end of the stream.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
using(BinaryWriter binWriter = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create)))
{
     binWriter.Write(what_you_want);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at BinaryFormatter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.71%29.aspx